# Stuck Thread issue in jersey restful service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have a stuck thread production issue on web sphare server,I have developed a jersey Restful web service for uploading document like pan id proof,address proof customer pic etc from tablet to service from multipart file upload that service consume by scheduler of apk after every 1 hours.
There are more then 100 user using the application. On production after 2 to 3 day
my web service got hanged due to stuck thread exception.

Please suggest me how to remove the stuck thread issue.Or restrict the service can only allow 10 request (concurrently) at a time

Comment: Read this, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564058/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-created-on-server-side-in-jersey-restful-web-serv   and this https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/limiting_threads_used_for_asynchronous

Comment: You can use Threadpool concept over here... It will help you to restrict working thread of application.